# use acl protected nsf in website

Tags: xpages

I 've some nsf (let's call them one.nsf and two.nsf)files for which anonymous doesn't have access.
Another nsf for example website.nsf contains unid's and filenames for some pictures and documents from those nsf files (one.nsf and two.nsf) . 
How can I show( I mean access) those pictures and documents in an "xpage" website ?
Do I have to create a kind of fictitious user on the server ?

Comment: If you want anonymous users to be able to see them, why not grant anonymous reader access to the database? Why add in what acts like a "hack" to fool your security setup? Doesn't that make auditing your security harder?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating an Agent or an XAgent which acts like a proxy to access the images / documents etc. in a different user context.

The agent runs in the context of the user / ID who has signed the agent - and this is the user who needs access to *one.nsf* and *two.nsf*. The XAgent could access the data with *sessionAsSigner* or *sessionAsSignerWithFullAccess* and return the result.

But keep in mind that this would create a security hole in your current application security: Why has only a limited user group access to your pictures? Why not allow access to these images / documents for public access users? Maybe it would be better to create a *three.nsf* which only contains the data which is accessible for every user and give access to public users to this db instead.

**EDIT**:
A while ago I have created a DocumentDataSource with allows higher access, but this bring you into the same security trouble: http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=723